# How to invoke a Rest API from BAMBOO

Tags: bamboo

I need to create a Bamboo task that task needs to invoke my project Rest API(http://host:port/api/......) to perform the business logic. Is it any way is there to achieve this? Where i need to mention my API URL and how it will pick my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Script task to invoke curl command as part of job. Project REST endpoint can be plan variable, if it doesn't change often.

Comment: Thanks..., Now as per my requirement i'm invoking a JOB from my java code and in that job have configured one of script task that task is invoking one of my rest API. Now that rest API is post call and it is expecting some of  input. Right now i'm sending static values to that API but i need to send request object from my java code where i'm invoking my job.

How can i send a request object to bamboo to execute that particular task?